# Is ti posible to get value name from related table this way

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok so I need to get data from the table this way but I would like to get 
Vehicle Maker name too

I tried using join or 
just doing `auth()->user()->vehicles->VehicleMaker` but it doesn't work

**Migration of Table Vehicle**

```
Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id');
    $table->bigInteger('category_id');
    $table->bigInteger('vehicle_maker_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->double('price', 8 , 2);
    $table->year('manufacture_year');
    $table->bigInteger('mileage');
    $table->string('vehicle_image');
    $table->boolean('admin_verification')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Migration of vehicle_makers**

```
Schema::create('vehicle_makers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(){

    $vehicles = auth()->user()->vehicles; -- what shoul i add here

    return view('/home', [
       'vehicles' => $vehicles
    ]);
}
```

**Edit**
I forget to mention that I already made a relationship and they work in artisan tinker when I try to do something like this:
    `Vehicles->find(1)->VehicleMaker`
What I want is to do is 
    `auth()->user()->vehicles` and get vehicle teble with vahicle_maker name not id so some kind of join that would work in this case

Comment: Did you set up any relationships?  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes I have added relationship and they work in artisan tinker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay base on [Laravel Model Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

You first need to create a `migration`.

**Vihicle Migration**

```
Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('vehicle_maker_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->double('price', 8 , 2);
    $table->year('manufacture_year');
    $table->bigInteger('mileage');
    $table->string('vehicle_image');
    $table->boolean('admin_verification')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> I used `unisignedBigInteger` to determine it is a foreign key or you can also use `index()`.

In your model you should place what relation ship you will use. In your case I assumed you are using [One To Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). So that your user model should look like this:

**User Model**

```
...
public function vehicles() {
  return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class);
}
```

> So that you can use the convention `auth()->user()->vehicles;`.
>
> Note: the `auth()->user()->vehicles;` return a `array of object` you can loop it in `foreach`.

**Vehicle Model**

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

> In when you have this in your model you can use it 2 way.

In your controller you can call the relationship of those 2.

**Controller**

```
$vehicles = auth()->user()->vehicles;

dd($vehicles);
```

**INFO**

You can also refer to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2wJWVQEFAU&t=280s).

**EDIT**

**Controller**

```
$vehicles = auth()->user()->vehicles();

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
 dd($vehicle->VehicleMaker);
}
```

> Note: The `$vehicles` is returning an array of object. So you can loop it through `foreach loop` to throw a single instance.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I wont to do. I already have those relationships made. See the edit that I made.

Comment: @PetarArandjic check my edit. I assumed that the `auth()->user()->vehicles;` is returning a collection of array. That's why I also assume that the collection you query is a `one to many relationship`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a relationship between the user and vehicles then another relationship between vehicles and vehicle_makers. If you already created your models(Vehicle, VehicleMaker) with their migrations, You can do the following

```
//add this to your User model.

public function vehicle(){
    return this->belongsTo(App\Vehicle);
}

// add this to your Vehicle model

public function user(){
    return this->hasMany(App\Vehicle); // implying that a user can have many vehicles
}

//add this to your vehicleMaker model

public function vehicle(){
    return this->belongsTo(App\Vehicle);
}
```

When that is done, you can use Laravel's lazy loading to fetch relationships. You can do something like

```
$vehicles = auth()->user()->vehicle
   return view('/home', [
   'vehicles' => $vehicles
]);
```

Comment: Thank you but that is not what I want to do. I already made relationships you can see an edit of my post for more info. Thanks, again